Azure server returns 403 forbiden for an api calls with special "is not"
I have a api (POST/PATCH) reside in the Azure server (using C#, net 8.0), It has a payload with class object with something like:
public class Employee
{

    [RegularExpression(@"^[^*$^`<>\”'=!@]{1,100}$")]
    public string Name {get;set;}
   ...

}

When the value of Name is: "this is not contact" it returns 403 forbidden
If we change the Name value to "this is nott contact" then it is ok.
It seems that if the string value has the format "*** is not ***" then it is not ok.
I tried the same exactly settings in my local server (docker) it is ok. So I am wondering if the Azure has some restriction on this "is not" keyword.
Does anyone have any ideas or know what setting we need to do in Azure? Thanks
We tried the following with Name property:
"This is not a contact", returns 403
"This is nnot a contact", returns 200
"This am not a contact", returns 200
"This is not", returns 200
"is not a contact", returns 200
"Anything is not anything", return 403

Are you deploying your web API to Azure App Service?

If Possible, share your code?

Did you enable Authentication/Authorization?

do you have a WAF ? the WAF maybe thinking is it SQL injection or something like that

Thanks a lot,  Aslesha Kantamsetti: Yes, we deploying to Azure App Service. It did not reach to our code and get blocked. We did authorize it otherwise, other in put for the Name will not be ok.

Thanks to  you, Thomas, I have to check with admin on this.

@Gordon968 I'm able to pass the "is not" value to Name parameter without any issues.
